# Pass login arguments to REST service

Tags: c#

Trying to call REST service using C# application:

```
namespace SrvClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        public class RestClient
        {
            public string EndPoint { get; set; }
            public HttpVerb Method { get; set; }
            public string ContentType { get; set; }
            public string PostData { get; set; }

            public RestClient()
            {
                EndPoint = "";
                Method = HttpVerb.GET;
                ContentType = "text/xml";
                PostData = "";
            }
            public RestClient(string endpoint)
            {
                EndPoint = endpoint;
                Method = HttpVerb.GET;
                ContentType = "text/xml";
                PostData = "";
            }
            public RestClient(string endpoint, HttpVerb method)
            {
                EndPoint = endpoint;
                Method = method;
                ContentType = "text/xml";
                PostData = "";
            }

            public RestClient(string endpoint, HttpVerb method, string postData)
            {
                EndPoint = endpoint;
                Method = method;
                ContentType = "text/xml";
                PostData = postData;
            }


            public string MakeRequest()
            {
                return MakeRequest("");
            }

            public string MakeRequest(string parameters)
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint + parameters);

                request.Method = Method.ToString();
                request.ContentLength = 0;
                request.ContentType = ContentType;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.PUT)
                {
                    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                    var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(PostData);
                    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                    using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }

                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    var responseValue = string.Empty;

                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                        throw new ApplicationException(message);
                    }

                    // grab the response
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (responseStream != null)
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                    }

                    return responseValue;
                }
            }

        } // class

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var client = new RestClient();
            client.EndPoint = @"http://localhost:11332";
            client.Method = HttpVerb.GET;
            client.PostData = "{postData: value}";
            var json = client.MakeRequest("/Account/Login");


        }
    }
}
```

As call result I have string:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n\t<title>Login -   My ASP.NET Application</title>\r\n\t\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n\t\t<p>Welcome <a href=\"/Account/Login\">login</a>)</p>\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\r\n<h2>Login</h2>\r\n\r\n<form action=\"/Account/Login\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"_fykbIPsr7u1kGba8zUirPqbqnMG_-eyztTSwSJxB3XksVdrUrLWjsyC9NXWugXn34AxZerny4coFb5_6ILNpMmmG4GZgI-U_Oqhl1VQSzk1\" />\t<p>username:<br /><input class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"UserName\" name=\"UserName\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /></p>\r\n\t<p>pin:<br /><input class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"Pin\" name=\"Pin\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /></p>\r\n\t<p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"login\" /></p>\r\n</form>\r\n\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/Content/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js\"></script>\r\n\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/Content/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js\"></script>\r\n\t\r\n\r\n<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->\r\n<script type=\"application/json\" id=\"__browserLink_initializationData\">\r\n    {\"appName\":\"Unknown\",\"requestId\":\"fba1d156c3114ecbbe989a83cd4616c7\"}\r\n</script>\r\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localhost:21213/b011fdffd90446038f2d9d01cd2a32bf/browserLink\" async=\"async\"></script>\r\n<!-- End Browser Link -->\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Looks like I need to login. How to make login call in this case?

Comment: Looks like you are hitting a web page, not a rest service. Check whether you are using the correct URL

Comment: Also, check that you are using the correct Verb, in many cases a login should be submitted using a POST request.

Comment: Ok, I will change to POST. But how to send username and password by using this address? Should I POST string like /Account/Login?Pass=pass&UserName=admin . How to know parameter passing syntax?